# How can I move display inline-block to the right?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that's within a display:inline-block. How do I move it to the right?

```
<div style='width:100%'>
left

<div style='display:inline-block;position:relative;right:0px'>
right
</div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/y5dt2prj/

Answer (score 10):

You can use `Flexbox` instead and set `margin-left: auto` on inner div to move it to right.

```html
<div style='display:flex;'>
  left
  <div style='margin-left: auto;'>
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a possible issue with this approach occurs when instead of "left" there is a text larger than the line so that the "right" div appears aside at the top, instead of at the end of the text

Answer (score 4):

use float right.  This should work for you:

```
<div style='display:inline-block;position:relative;float:right;'>
right
</div>
```

Comment: After 30 minutes of searching the web, ```float: right``` was exactly what solved my problem. ```Flexbox``` is too expensive for what I'm doing, so this was the best answer for me.

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach to position an inline-block element uses the relative positioning approach as follows:

```
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 100%;
transform: translateX(-100%);
```

Answer (score 0):

style="display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse"

or if your using Bootstrap: class="d-flex flex-row-reverse"

This worked for me when I had a following element with overflow, i.e. scroll bars on.